# Subset Sum Algorithm. Print True or False along with all possible subset equal to given sum

Tags: python

This is my Code and I want the **Desired Output** but just getting **Output**....Pls Help Me!!
https://github.com/amitsgh/Algorithm/commit/37529df890a23dae154cbd0e69e0de82e1f2d412

Output:
True
[8, 2]

Desired Output:
True
[8, 2], [6, 4]

Comment: Please do not provide code in this manner.  You should copy your code from github and included it directly in your question.

Comment: Well I have tried but the code was showing in the form of text. How I'm I supposed to do that and I have also used the code option. @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated, and you don't need recursion to accomplish this task.  Here's a very straightforward way to get what you want:

```
def subset_sum(sum, values):
     result = []
     for i in range(len(values)):
          for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
               if values[i] + values[j] == sum:
                    result.append((values[i], values[j]))
     return result

r = subset_sum(10, [2, 6, 4, 8])

print("{} {}".format("True" if len(r) > 0 else "False", r))
```

Result:

```
True [(2, 8), (6, 4)]
```

You didn't say what should determine if `True` or `False` is printed.  I assumed it was if at least one pair of values was found that added up to the provided sum.

Comment: I was just learning Algorithm and it was done with the concept of knapsack dynamic programming that's why it is so clumsy!!

Comment: Can you make it O(n)  time complexity @Steve

Comment: I don't know of a simple way to make this O(N).  It might somehow be doable with trickier code, but I don't know of a way off hand.  My guess is that there's no way to get an O(N) solution because you're always going to have roughly N * (N/2) pairs to test.  So this simple method is O(N^2).  Maybe there's some trickier solution that is in between O(N) and O(N^2)